# Project/Task fields depending on stage

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I need to change field to read-only based on stage.
So in Project/Tasks there is stage_ids. For example i have 3 stages if my task in stage 2 i need to make date_deadline field read-only and if it in stage 1 it should be required .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by setting attr on field in xml

```
<field name="date_deadline"  attrs=" {
   'required':[('stage_id','in',[1])],
   'readonly':[('stage_id','not in',[2])]}"
/>
```

and here,

> [1],[2] are the stage_ids
>   in attrs